# Dns lookup failed

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

So, my problem is my computer can't connect to the internet. When i turned on my computer this morning, everything booted up like normal, but when i open up a browser window and navigate to a page, it says "Dns Lookup failed". I use Windows 7 64-bit google chrome 11.0. But the weird thing is that other programs that use the internet are unaffected. And everyone else on the network is fine. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Congratulations, you are a [IPv6 day](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_IPv6_Day) victim!

Comment: If other programs work, then you *can* connect tot he Internet, the problem is with Chrome. Please edit your question to include your operating system and Chrome version.

Comment: can you ping 72.14.213.147? that is one of google's IPs. If you can hit that, but you get nothing when pinging google.com, then there is an issue with the way your computer is handling DNS resolution.

Comment: yup, i can ping that address. How do i fix DNS resolution though? Do i just contact my isp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the google open dns addresses, 
8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

or even OpenDNS (http://www.opendns.com/)

Comment: This implies that, as daxim said in a comment on the question, your ISP (your old DNS provider) doesn't support IPV6, so on IPV6 day lookup broke.

Answer (score 0):

Open CMD and type `ipconfig /flushdns` and try connecting again.

Also, set your DNS servers to open servers like Google's, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4